# YoctoProject error with automake and system clock

Tags: docker, build, clock, yocto

Im running yocto to build an image inside docker, but after all processes i get error related to automake. This is the error:

```
checking whether build environment is sane...
configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
```

[image]

The log is:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
NOTE: Running ../automake-1.15.1/configure  --build=x86_64-linux          --host=x86_64-linux         --target=x86_64-linux           --prefix=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr        --exec_prefix=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr           --bindir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin        --sbindir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin          --libexecdir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/libexec        --datadir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share         --sysconfdir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc        --sharedstatedir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/com        --localstatedir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/var         --libdir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib        --includedir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include        --oldincludedir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include         --infodir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/info        --mandir=/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man          --disable-silent-rules          --disable-dependency-tracking             --disable-static  
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-dependency-tracking, --disable-static
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/hosttools/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
NOTE: /shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/build/config.log
ERROR: configure failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.11873)
```

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use ?

Comment: What does "date" run on the commandline show?

Comment: make run cmd="date":  

Tue Dec 19 22:36:08 UTC 2017

Answer (score 0):

In latest Yocto version, there is this [patch](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake/performance.patch) that removes clock sanity check.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But how i can use it? Im using yocto 2.4, this is the latest version.

Comment: Can you check if it is applied anyway in `/shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15.1-r0/`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. If i list files i have:

```
    0001-automake-Add-default-libtool_tag-to-cppasm.patch
    automake-1.15.1
    automake-replace-w-option-in-shebangs-with-modern-use-    warnings.patch
    build
    buildtest.patch
    new_rt_path_for_test-driver.patch
    performance.patch
    python-libdir.patch
    recipe-sysroot
    recipe-sysroot-native
    temp
```

Comment: And all the .patch files is:

``
0001-automake-Add-default-libtool_tag-to-cppasm.patch
new_rt_path_for_test-driver.patch
automake-replace-w-option-in-shebangs-with-modern-use-warnings.patch
python-libdir.patch
buildtest.patch
performance.patch
``

Comment: What is the result for `grep -RI 'Check your system clock' /shared/rpi3-custom/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-nat‌​ive/1.15.1-r0/ ` please ?

Comment: I have upload all to:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/docker-yocto. And the result of command is here: https://gist.github.com/prsolucoes/a73129f7ee8d126cb9ac5fcc66a45555.

Comment: Can't you synchronise your docker with ntp before building? you can always create a new patch for configure.ac and configure that removes clock check, but i'm not sure it is a good idea...

Comment: [Here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-a-quilt-workflow) is how to use quilt to generate a patch. You can try to remove from something like line 2263 to 2297 of configure file.

Comment: Hi Nayfe. But on performance.patch file, already have lines that remove System clock check. Check here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf4ghqxay06rm2i/Screenshot%202017-12-18%2019.13.47.png?dl=1. After check here: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake/performance.patch#n54. What i do?

Comment: performance.patch is patching sanity.m4 file. You need to make another one if you go that way.

Comment: Hi, i make the patch but errors happend that patch inside files folder is not found and is not on search paths. I put the log on readme on repository: https://github.com/prsolucoes/docker-yocto. Patch is here: https://github.com/prsolucoes/docker-yocto/blob/master/shared/rpi3-custom/meta-rpi/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_%25.bbappend

Comment: Hi, i made the patch but error happen when patch will be applied. The path generated by quilt is wrong. See: https://github.com/prsolucoes/docker-yocto

Comment: I think your `automake_%.bbappend` should have `SRC_URI +=` instead of `SRC_URI = `. Try to generate patch inside `automake-1.15.1` folder instead of parent folder.